# How to make KDE4 System Settings app work if kde-workspace is in a custom install prefix?

Tags: kde, kde4, kwin

For various reasons I need to use KWin from KDE4 on Ubuntu 18.04. I've compiled `kde-workspace-4.11.22` package from source, having installed all the required development packages from the Ubuntu repositories. To avoid messing with the system files, I chose the install prefix to be `~/opt/kde4`. Then KWin works fine if I launch it with

```
PATH=~/opt/kde4/lib/kde4/libexec/:$PATH ~/opt/kde4/bin/kwin
```

If I simply run it without adding `libexec` to `PATH`, I get no compositing because KWin can't check that it works.

So far so good. But I also need to tweak some KDE4-specific KWin settings (e.g. window decoration style, buttons), and `kde-workspace` does have the `systemsettings` app. I launch it, and get an error:

> System Settings was unable to find any views, and hence has nothing to display.

So my question is, how to inform System Settings app of the path to the settings plugins? The installation prefix does contain lots of `~/opt/kde4/lib/kde4/kcm_*.so` files, but apparently they aren't found.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use chroot and eventually have your kde4 install there. A simple way to do that is [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/#chroot)

An other possible solution is to sim-link your library to the location they should be in `sudo ln -s ${HOME}/opt/kde4/lib /usr/lib/kde4` (if it suit your needs)

Also try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/opt/kde4/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` before running `systemsettings`

Note that you can check your kcm with `kcmshell4 --list`

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't help. Apparently, `systemsettings` doesn't take this variable into account when looking for its plugins. And using chroot looks like an overkill: just to set some settings I need basically a duplicate of the root file system. The linking will mess with the system-provided directory with the same name.

Comment: i personally migrated some kcm v4 to kcm v5 because they where unavailable on kde v5 and then managed them with systemsettings5, if that would be helpful for you let me know i'll explain how to do it.